# Sqoop import error message ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: ENOENT: No such file or directory Options

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Getting error while running the sqoop import statement

sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db \
    --username retail_dba \
    --password cloudera  \
    --table orders \
    --target-dir /user/cloudera/problem1/orders \
    --compress \
    --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
    --as-avrodatafile;

Error message

17/11/06 21:56:30 WARN security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE) cause:ENOENT: No such file or directory
17/11/06 21:56:30 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: ENOENT: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:716)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1304)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1304)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1325)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:203)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:176)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:273)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:513)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:621)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

Comment: can you check with existence of table, is it under same user <retail_dba>

Comment: when I run the same command from root user it's working but when run from the Cloudera user it's throwing this error.

Comment: check for permissions and user, where you have installed sqoop, is it  root or cloudera user @user3596103

Comment: check if there is already files under target directory